# System process causes 10% CPU usage when doing nothing

Tags: windows-10, drivers, cpu, performance, cpu-usage

So I have a MSI laptop and about 2 days ago when I opened Task Manager I noticed a surge in CPU usage even when I'm doing nothing.

**Process Explorer**
[image: Process Explorer]

Can anyone help me what caused this problem and offer a solution ?

This is the link to compressed ETL file: [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gjdL0AudRFd6SZUXn40nGaSCifilmjCF/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @John yes, this also happens. Task Manager displays 100% CPU usage after opening, then it reduces to 10 - 20%.

Comment: @John The system is definitely not normal. 50C on CPU and 49C on GPU for doing nothing is not something normal.

Comment: 50 degrees C is fairly normal. I have a good ThinkPad here and temps are 45 to 50 C just idling and the Laptop is quite cool. What is your CPU % running after 30 minutes?

Comment: @John Not much different, still 10 - 20%. My laptop is not cool at all, plus Task Manager show that System' Power Usage and Power Usage trend is Moderate up to High.

By the way, have you taken a look at my ETL file ? I'm not sure but I think it has something related to NVIDIA drivers. The System process also uses 1 - 2% GPU0, which is the Intel UHD 630. Anychance my laptop is infected with RAT, cryptominer ?

Comment: The NVLDDMKM process has a high delta value (not crazy though). AFAIK, this indicates the number of context switches during a single ProcessExplorer refresh period. This process has had security vulnerabilities in the past. https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4278/~/security-bulletin%3A-multiple-vulnerabilities-in-the-nvidia-windows-gpu-display

Comment: Hmm.. When I try to do a Clean Boot, turn off all services except Microsoft services, the CPU average usage drop down to 1 - 4%, the temperature also drops to 38 - 42C. Definitely this has something related to those drivers or start-up load modules.. @Yorik

Comment: Note also that many laptops use the GPU on the CPU die unless under load at which point they switch to the dedicated one. Perhaps you are running on that threshold and the computer keeps alternating between the two. This might account for the other entries re: power-on state

Comment: Try to turn off "in-game overlay" in GeForce Experience. https://superuser.com/a/1718590/114318

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1619607/system-process-at-10-cpu-when-not-using-computer might help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read your system is running at an average for most machines running windows 10. To reduce this further, you will need to close / disable all non-window apps that came with windows 10. If you have had the latest windows 10 update this month check that your windows defender is turned on, specially the app & browser control is still on. By trimming unneeded programes you should be able to get your cpu usage down to 2%.

Just be prepared to do this process every time an update is installed as microsoft update sees missing or inactive programes as a fault and runs default settings to fix the error they see as an error, even if it is as it should be.