# "System" process at >10% CPU when not using computer

Tags: windows, windows-10, cpu, fan

If I step away from my laptop, after a few minutes, I'll often hear the fans spin up. I was wondering what process might be doing this so I left *Task Manager* open. Here's what I noticed was at the top when this happens:

[image]

If I move the mouse, the CPU usage of "System" drops and the fans spin down after a bit.

I noticed this popular question on superuser:

[Troubleshoot High CPU usage by the "System" process](https://superuser.com/questions/527401/troubleshoot-high-cpu-usage-by-the-system-process)

However, the approach there doesn't appear to be applicable since as I mention above, if interact with the system, the issue goes away. So If I attempt to use the diagnostic tools, the issue is not longer occuring.

Any suggestions on what might be causing 'System' to run at this high rate?

**UPDATE**

OK, I went ahead with approach in the linked post as recommended by the comments below.

For reference, here's how I started `wpr.exe`:

```
wpr.exe -start GeneralProfile
```

I then waited for the fans to spin up (took about 5 minutes). I left the system alone for about a minute. I then stopped `wpr.exe`:

```
wpr.exe -stop abc.etl
```

Here's the data as shown in Windows Performance Analyzer:

[image]

The linked post has a section on:

```
ntoskrnl.exe!RtlpGenericRandomPatternWorker
```

which seems to be the issue here. Looking into that now. :-)

**UPDATE**

When I open the *Task Scheduler* and look under:

```
Microsoft > Windows > MemoryDiagnostic > RunFullMemoryDiagnostic
```

I see the following:

[image]

**UPDATE**

After the issue occurred again, I refreshed *Task Scheduler* and indeed, the 'Last Run Time' for `RunFullMemoryDiagnostic` was updated:

[image]

So it seems that maybe when the system is idle, `RunFullMemoryDiagnostic` begins to run (fans spin up) and then it ends ("terminated unexpectedly"). Since it didn't complete, it just keeps trying.

If I do a google search for:

```
"RunFullMemoryDiagnostic" "the process terminated unexpectedly"
```

only 4 results come up.

**UPDATE**

For now, I've set `RunFullMemoryDiagnostic` to `Disabled`.

Comment: It may just be normal processes checking for updates and scanning files for viruses. For some time now, Task Manager goes to 100% CPU for a few seconds. I open it and minimize to the system tray when not using it. If your system is otherwise normal (adjusting for the things above), there may not be any problem.

Comment: The answer by magicandre1981 most certainly applies to Windows 10.  In fact the entire answer specifically mentions Windows 10.  Have you performed any of the steps in the answer outlined by magicandre1981?

Comment: You start the diagnostic tools *before* the problem happens.

Comment: Initially, can you get a ETL trace of this?  For example: Open an admin prompt and run:
`wpr.exe -start GeneralProfile` leave it running.  Do you see the issue after leaving this for a couple of minutes?  Hopefully yes.  If you leave the problem happening for 10-20 seconds, then run: `wpr.exe -stop C:\generalProfile.etl`.  At least at this point you have a trace that captures the issue.

Comment: Once you have generated the appropriate report be sure to [edit] your question otherwise we won’t be notified of the anything

Comment: @Ramhound Yup, I just updated it with the analysis data. :-) Thanks for the encouragement to press on with magicandre1981's approach!

Comment: You need to expand the individual items to list the contents.  We cannot explain anything based off that screenshot of that report

Comment: @harrymc It usually takes a few minutes for the issue to kick in and I originally thought the data dump would be too large. However, I went ahead and did as you suggested and it wasn't prohibitively large (2GB or so). I've updated my question with the resulting data. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @HelpingHand Thank you for the suggestion. I've updated the question with the results of the analysis.

Comment: @Ramhound As far as I can tell, I've expanded the elements as much as possible. Note that it shows `ntoskrnl.exe!RtlpGenericRandomPatternWorker` which is mentioned in the linked post.

Comment: So if you edit the task - "Conditions" say, from the default of 10 mins to 20 mins of idle that all fits?  If you manually start it the CPU usage occurs?  What about, if you run Process Monitor, manually kick off the task, leave it 1 min.  Stop the capture (include System process), in the Tree view, find the svchost process that is the Scheduler service, i.e. `C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs -p -s Schedule`. A child of this is the "C:\WINDOWS\system32\taskhostw.exe" process. Does it look to be having issues?

Comment: @HelpingHand Yup, if I manually start `RunFullMemoryDiagnostic`, CPU goes to about 12% and stays there for many minutes. I've set `RunFullMemoryDiagnostic` to `Disabled` for now.

Comment: Could you in the Task Scheduler show a screenshot for `RunFullMemoryDiagnostic` of its Triggers pane?

Comment: @harrymc The `Triggers` section is empty for `RunFullMemoryDiagnostic`.

Comment: Sorry, my (deleted) answer was based on a wrong click. My Triggers section is also empty for `RunFullMemoryDiagnostic`, so it seems to be started automatically by Windows. You could keep it disabled, or start doing general troubleshooting for Windows. I can make suggestions for that, if you wish to spend more time on the problem.

Comment: PowerShell command to disable the task: `Disable-ScheduledTask -TaskName "\Microsoft\Windows\MemoryDiagnostic\RunFullMemoryDiagnostic"`