# "System" using abnormal high CPU usage linked to NVIDIA graphic card

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, cpu, nvidia, high-cpu-usage

I know many they have been many discussions about the "system using high CPU" already and I have been trying to solve this problem on my Dell XPS 15 9510 with an NVIDIA RTX 3050Ti ( relevant for later) using many solutions from users and I have concluded using Windows Performance Analyser that the process using all that power was "Nvlddmkm.sys", so I tried reinstalling the driver but it doesn't work.

Then I tried messing with the NVIDIA Control Panel and found out the weirdest thing:

When I'm at idle, no apps running, system is using 8-20% of CPU usage killing my battery life
But when I simply open the NVIDIA control panel and Select the "Adjust image setting with preview" page, system goes down on the task manager to about 0.1% of CPU usage and my battery life is back to normal ! It doesn't work on any other page of the NVIDIA Control Panel.

I'm running windows 11, with an Intel i7 11800H 2.30GHz , NVIDIA RTX3050Ti graphics card, 16gb of ram.

Do you have any idea why that is how i could fix this issue (without having to open the NVIDIA control panel all the time) ?

[Here are the results of the WPA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9TMe.png)

[With the symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq5Ca.png)

Comment: Can you share the etl file capturing the issue? I assume when you had the issue, you ran: `wpr.exe -start GeneralProfile` left it 15 seconds and ran `wpr.exe -stop C:\gp.etl`. That should be enough.

Comment: Thanks, I just added a screenshot of the WPA.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/527401/troubleshoot-high-cpu-usage-by-the-system-process Does an older version of the driver have the same problem? If not, rollback.

Comment: Can you share the etl, there are no symbols and you'd need to expand the stacks more.

Comment: @Gantendo I dont think this is a driver related problem cause I had the issue before and reinstalling windows solve it but unfortunately it came back after a few months…

Comment: @ThomasMarquet That sucks, because driver-related problems are relatively easy to solve.

Comment: @HelpingHand okay I'll do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This EXACT same issue occured on my Laptop 2 days ago, even with the CPU usage going down when being tabbed into the NVIDIA control panel, and the Nvlddmkm.sys being the main problem.

After a lot of simply trying things, just **disabling the ingame overlay** in **the GeForce Experience settings** solved it for me.

The CPU usage from "System" is now Back to >1%.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me too !